# Enqueuing simultaneous async requests in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a very big list of urls and I need to call multiple external REST API endpoints with these urls to fetch the rest of the data. This data is then inserted into the database.

Below is the code snippet that fetches the data from the REST API and stores the result into the database:

```
// Opening storage model
await storageModel.open();

// Iterate through all the links
for (let idx = 0; idx < links.length; idx++)
{
    console.log("Checking link %j of %j", idx+1, links.length);
    link = links[idx];

    // Getting link data (slow)
    try {
        let data = await checkLinkAndGetData(linkGetter, link);
        await storageModel.insert(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
        // Processing some errors
        ...
    }
}

await storageModel.close();
```

The performance of this code is very poor, since it waits for the Promises to resolve before proceeding to the next link. What I want is to "enqueue" 5-10 async calls (without waiting on them) and make the loop to proceed to the next links only when some of the "enqueued" Promises got resolved.

P.S. I'm using native Promises, not Bluebird.

Comment: yeah, so, don't use await. await does precisely the opposite of what you're trying to do. Collect the promises in an array then use promise.all to determine when they're all complete.

Comment: @KevinB, I need to process 300-500 thousands of links.

Comment: so? doesn't change the fact that await will not do what you're waning it to. await will pause the loop until the promise being awaited is done. It will then continue to the next one, and so on.

Comment: Take your 500k length array, chunk it into smaller 5-10 entry chunks, and process them.

Comment: @KevinB, Promise.all will wait until all Promises got resolved, I would like to start processing new links as any of queued promises got resolved.

Comment: if you want things to happen simultaneously, and you want to know when the things happening simultaneously are all complete so you can move on to the next set of things, that's what promise.all is for.

Comment: @ezpresso, You can put the insert code inside the `.then()` method on a js Promise to run that code asynchronously after the promise is resolved. If you use this instead of `await` your loop will fire off all of the API requests without waiting and the results will be fed into the callback given in `.then()`. This might send too many requests at once though.

Comment: @Romen, Will there be any problems with firing 200k Promises at once?

Comment: @ezpresso promises, no, but what the promises are waiting on, quite possibly.

Comment: @ezpresso, It's always possible that the API you're sending these requests to might not be able to keep up or defensively ignore requests. (Is this API on a system you control too?) You could use counters to track requests sent vs responses handled and sleep in the loop whenever that difference gets too high.

Comment: @Romen, yes. It seems it will need some kind of "throttling".

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create the promises 5-10 at a time, storing them in an array, and `await`ing `Promise.all(promises)`.  For example:

```js
// Opening storage model
await storageModel.open();

// Iterate through all the links
for (let block = 0; block < links.length; block += 10)
{
    const promises = [];

    // Collect promises in blocks of 10.
    for (let idx = block; idx < links.length && idx < block + 10; idx++)
    {
        console.log("Checking link %j of %j", idx+1, links.length);
        link = links[idx];

        promises.push(checkLinkAndGetData(linkGetter, link));
    }

    try {
        // Wait for all 10 promises to finish (in any order).
        let data = await Promise.all(promises);

        // Still await each insert so that the ordering is maintained.
        for (let idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++)
        {
            await storageModel.insert(data);
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        // Processing some errors
        ...
    }
}

await storageModel.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Actually I thought of using Promise.all, but it has a number of issues: (1) it will wait for all 10 requests to complete; (2) the returning promise will be rejected if any of the input Promises is rejected.